# Insert data from label to MySql python

Tags: python

I want to add a label value in my database from MySQL. I want to do this because I don't want to make the user to select data every time he insert anythig.
Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import mysql.connector
import datetime


def Ok():
    tip=e1.get()
    descriere=e2.get()
    data=e3.get()
    timp=e4.get()

    mysqldb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="", database="reglog")
    mycursor= mysqldb.cursor()

    try:
        sql = "INSERT INTO anunturib(id,tip,descriere,data,timp) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
        val = ("",tip,descriere,data,timp)
        mycursor.execute(sql,val)
        mysqldb.commit()
        messagebox.showinfo("information","Record inserted succesfully!")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        mysqldb.rollback()
        mysqldb.close()

        

root= Tk();
root.title("Anunturi")
root.geometry("300x250")
global e1
global e2
global e3
global e4



Label(root,text="Tip cerere:").place(x=10,y=10)
Label(root,text="Descriere").place(x=10,y=40)
Label(root,text="Data publicare:").place(x=10,y=80)
Label(root,text="Data expirare:").place(x=10,y=120)

TodayDate = datetime.datetime.now()
an = TodayDate.strftime("%Y")
luna = TodayDate.strftime("%m")
zi = TodayDate.strftime("%d")
data=zi + "-" + luna + "-" + an

e3=Label(root,text=data).place(x=148,y=80)


e1 = Entry(root)
e1.place(x=148,y=10)

e2 = Entry(root)
e2.place(x=148,y=40)



e4 = Entry(root)
e4.place(x=148,y=120)

Button(root,text="Add",command=Ok ,height=3, width=13).place(x=10,y=180)

root.mainloop()
```

I didn't find anything related to this. In this way I get the error:
data=e3.get()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: `e3=Label(root,text=data).place(x=148,y=80)` will assign the return value of `Label.place()` to `e3`.  I'm guessing that value is `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is close to you! What you need is the value of the label, and what is the value of the label? The variable `data`. So you can not use `e3.get()` for 2 reasons. Firstly, `get()` does not exist for `Label`. Secondly, the text of the label is whatever the value of `data` is. So you can plainly just insert it:

```
def Ok():
    tip=e1.get()
    descriere=e2.get()
    # data=e3.get() # Don't define `data`, so `data` is the old data defined before
    timp=e4.get()
    ....
    ....
```

Also you dont need to manually get the day, month and year and make it all to a string. Instead make use of `strftime` like:

```
today_date = datetime.datetime.now()
fmt = '%d-%m-%Y' # Format you want to change a datetime obj to
data = datetime.datetime.strftime(today_date,fmt)
```

It also feels like mentioning, you can always get the text of the label with `e3.cget('text')` or `e3['text']`. But we don't need it here as it is just the variable `data`.

Also to understand why you got the initial `AttributeError`, read: [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Answer (score 0):

Change `e3=Label(root,text=data).place(x=148,y=80)` to

```py
e3=Label(root,text=data)
e3.place(x=148,y=80)
```

Comment: Ok, now I get this error:   File "C:\xampp\htdocs\licenta\python\insert.py", line 10, in Ok
    data=e3.get()
AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: The problem is just what the error message says it is.  `e3` contains a reference to a `Label` object, and a `Label` object does not have an attribute named `get`...that is, it doesn't support the method `get()`.  An `Entry` object does have a `get()`  method.  That is why the two `get()` calls prior to the one that is failing work fine. - Kinda makes sense, right?  A Label is just a visual thing...it doesn't accept input, so it doesn't make sense to try to get a value back from it.

Comment: Ok, that was clear. Did you have any other option to get that date? I mean maybe I store it in another object?